# How to connect data points (for each subject) on a plot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm plotting each subject's proportion of responses to "same" or "different" stimuli across two blocks (A block and B block), meaning that each subject has 4 data points plotted. Two for A block (same and different) and two for B block (same and different). Also means there are 4 rows of data containing proportion of responses for each subject.

I would like to connect each subject's "same" and
"different" data points with a line WITHIN a block (e.g. their one datapoint for "same" and datapoint for "different" are connected via a line within the A block and within the B block for each subject).

I tried using the "group = subject" that comes with geom_line(), but it connects ALL of the subject's data points when I would like to only connect data points within each block.

```
testplot <- ggplot(df, aes(x=block, y=prop, shape=con, colour=con)) +
  geom_point(position=position_dodge(width=.1)) +
  xlab("Block") + ylab("Prop of responses") +
  theme_bw(base_size = 13) +
  theme(legend.position="top")
plot(testplot)
```

sample dataset:

```
subj = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4)
prop = c(0.5, 0.8, 0.3, 0.7, 0.9, 0.4, 0.1, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.9, 0.2, 0.7, 0.4, 0.8, 0.1)
con = c("same", "same", "same", "same", "same", "same", "same", "same", "diff", "diff", "diff", "diff", "diff", "diff", "diff", "diff")
block = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B")

df = data.frame(subj, prop, con, block)
```

I hope this makes sense, is this feasible? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the best approach is with a `facet_grid`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=con, y=prop, shape=con)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=con), position=position_dodge(width=.1)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = subj)) +
  facet_grid(.~block) +
  xlab("Block") + ylab("Prop of responses") +
  theme_bw(base_size = 13) +
  theme(legend.position="top")
```

[image]

Comment: Very good. +1, but is the legend necessary given that the x-axis already contains this explanation? You could use colour/ shape to represent subject in the legend.

Comment: @Edward Probably not, but it was in the OP's original question and they used both symbol and color to call attention to `con`. Additionally, the difference between symbols might not be clear.

Answer (score 7):

One approach to achieve your desired plot would be to use `facet_wrap` by `block`, map `con` on `x` and `subj` on `group`. Try this:

```r
subj = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4)
prop = c(0.5, 0.8, 0.3, 0.7, 0.9, 0.4, 0.1, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.9, 0.2, 0.7, 0.4, 0.8, 0.1)
con = c("same", "same", "same", "same", "same", "same", "same", "same", "diff", "diff", "diff", "diff", "diff", "diff", "diff", "diff")
block = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B")

df = data.frame(subj, prop, con, block)

library(ggplot2)

testplot <- ggplot(df, aes(x=con, y=prop, group = subj)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape=con, colour=con)) +
  geom_line() +
  xlab("Block") + ylab("Prop of responses") +
  theme_bw(base_size = 13) +
  theme(legend.position="top") +
  facet_wrap(~block, strip.position = "bottom") +
  theme(strip.placement = "outside", axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks.x = element_blank())
testplot
```

[image]

Comment: Haha, sorry I edited my answer to be your answer about 30 seconds before you posted. Take a +1.

Comment: @IanCampbell. +1 for you. (;

Comment: Both of you guys made it

Answer (score 7):

From looking at the other answers here, I perhaps misinterpreted, but I think this is possibly a clearer representation anyway:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(factor(subj), prop)) +
  geom_point(aes(fill = con), size = 3, shape = 21) +
  geom_line(aes(group = factor(subj))) +
  facet_grid(.~block, switch = "x") +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(2, 2)) +
  labs(x = "Subjects within block") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 12),
        strip.placement = "outside",
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_line(colour = "gray90"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This answer is very similar to the one by Ian Cambell but with colour and shape used to represent the subject since the same/diff is shown on the x-axis and is therefore redundant in the legend. With the subjects easily identifiable, the plot is also similar to the one by Allan Cameron. Just to show another perspective.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=con, y=prop, col=subj, shape=subj)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(group = subj)) +
  facet_grid(.~block) +
  xlab("Block") + ylab("Prop of responses") +
  theme_bw(base_size = 13) +
  theme(legend.position="top")
```

[image]

We can then compare the four subjects across the blocks (facets).

Comment: Looks good, but no need for `position_dodge` if you’re mapping `con` to `x`.

Comment: Yes - you're right. I shamelessly just copied your code and modified the aesthetics!

Answer (score 1):

These are all good suggestions and interesting ideas if you want to reconsider your data representation (facets in particular), but to *actually* answer your question, you want to **paste** the groups together, as in `geom_line(aes(group=paste(subj, con)))`

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=block, y=prop, shape=con, colour=con)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(group=paste(subj, con))) +
  xlab("Block") + ylab("Prop of responses") +
  theme_bw(base_size = 13) +
  theme(legend.position="top")
```

[image: result plot]